# How to print value from eval function

Tags: php, eval

I have a table 'test_config'.I have a field 'config_name','config_value'.

```
config_name |  config_value
____________________________ 
    test    |    "if($test=='1'){echo 'hello executive if part';}
            |    else{echo 'executive else part';}"
```

In my php page I have the code as

```
<?php
        $test='1';
        $bottom=DB::table('test_config')->where('config_name','test')->first()->config_value;
        eval("\$bottom=\"$bottom\";");
        print_r($bottom);
        ?>
```

I want to print only 'hello executive if part'. I caught the error '
FatalErrorException in  eval()'d code line 1:
syntax error, unexpected if (T_IF)'

Comment: Did you try using eval($bottom); ?

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me:

```
<?php
$test='1';
$bottom="if($test=='1'){echo 'hello executive if part';} else{ echo 'executive else part';} ";
eval($bottom);
//print_r($bottom);
?>
```

Or use like this:

```
<?php
$test='1';
$bottom="if($test=='1'){echo 'hello executive if part';} else{ echo 'executive else part';}";
eval("\$bottom=\"$bottom\";");
eval($bottom);
?>
```